# How to group by a column on a dataframe and applying single value to columns of all rows grouped?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe(scala) and I want to do something like below on the dataframe:

[image]

I want to group by column 'a' and select any of the value from column 1 out of the grouped columns and apply it on all rows.I.e for a=1, then b should be either x or y or h on all 3 rows and the rest of the columns should be unaffected.
any help on this?

Comment: can you share the actual dataframe also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, i.e, create another data frame that contains `a, b` columns where `b` has one value per `a` and then join it back with the original data frame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

val w = Window.partitionBy($"a").orderBy($"b")  
// create the window object so that we can create a column that gives unique row number 
// for each unique a

(df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).select("a", "b")
// create the row number column for each unique a and choose the first row for each group
// which returns a reduced data frame one row per group

   .join(df.select("a", "c"), Seq("a"), "inner").show)
// join the reduced data frame back with the original data frame(a,c columns), then b column 
// will have just one value

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  h|  g|
|  1|  h|  y|
|  1|  h|  x|
|  2|  c|  d|
|  2|  c|  x|
```

Comment: Just added the explanation.